# Visual Studio and multiple merge/compare tools

Tags: visual-studio, merge, diff

When you configure custom Merge or Compare tools in Visual Studio (eg. through the 'Configure User Tools' dialog when using TFS Source Control), you are only allowed to have one merge tool defined for a particular file extension.

Are there any extensions or 'shim'-like tools that allow using multiple diff tools (and prompting you to choose which one)?

eg. I usually use Beyond Compare for all my diffing/merging, but I'm interested in being able to using something else like Plastic SCM's Semantic Merge in certain situations.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a simple winforms app you write yourself.

Comment: You might be right! Was hoping someone else had beat me to it :-)

Answer (score 0):

David, you can set up Semantic as the default and then launch your ordinary one clicking on the "run mergetool" button. So you can have both Semantic and Beyond and you choose when to use each one.